# How to make a procedure that can have different input arguments for each type extending the original type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a derived type:

```
module type_1_mod
  implicit none

  public :: type1

  type :: type1
    private
    integer :: a, b
  contains
    procedure, public :: mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends
  end type type1

contains

  subroutine mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends(this, varInt, varReal, varLogic)
    class(type1) :: this
    integer :: varInt
    real :: varReal
    logical :: varLogic

    *** something ***
  end subroutine mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends

end module type_1_mod
```

I want to declare other derived types that will extend this one that I wrote above and all of them will have the procedure `mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends`, but I want this procedure to have no mandatory structure - meaning that the user can override the procedure by another one with different input arguments, for instance:

```
module type_2_mod
  use type_1_mod
  implicit none

  public :: type2

  type, extends(type1) :: type2
    private
  contains
    procedure, public :: mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends
  end type type2

contains

  subroutine mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends(this, varReal, varReal2, varReal3, varReal4, varLogic)
    class(type2) :: this
    real :: varReal, varReal2, varReal3, varReal4,
    logical :: varLogic

    *** something ***
  end subroutine mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends

end module type_2_mod
```

So the type extending type1 has a procedure with the same name, but redefined to have a different number and type of variables.

I have tried to write type1 as an abstract and use a deferred procedure, but these ones require to explicit declare an interface with the procedure structure already. I have also tried to use something like

**On type1 declaration**

```
  contains
    procedure, public :: type1VersionOfMandatory
    generic :: mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends => type1VersionOfMandatory

contains

  subroutine type1VersionOfMandatory(this, varInt, varReal, varLogic)
    class(type1) :: this
    integer :: varInt
    real :: varReal
    logical :: varLogic

    *** something ***
  end subroutine type1VersionOfMandatory
```

**On type2 declaration**

```
  contains
    procedure, public :: type2VersionOfMandatory
    generic :: mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends => type2VersionOfMandatory

contains

  subroutine type2VersionOfMandatory(this, varReal, varReal2, varReal3, varReal4, varLogic)
    class(type2) :: this
    real :: varReal, varReal2, varReal3, varReal4,
    logical :: varLogic

    *** something ***
  end subroutine type2VersionOfMandatory
```

But I receive an error when trying to compile: `Error: Undefined specific binding ‘type1VersionOfMandatory’ as target of GENERIC ‘mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends’ at (1)` and `Error: Undefined specific binding ‘type2VersionOfMandatory’ as target of GENERIC ‘mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends’ at (1)`

I have also tried to simply override the procedure by defining it with the same name again but I got some errors like `Error: Dummy argument ‘varInt’ of ‘mandatoryProcedureForAllExtends’ at (1) should be named ‘varReal’ as to match the corresponding argument of the overridden procedure`

So at this point I'm not even sure if it is possible to do this with fortran. I prefer type1 not be an Abstract type, but if this is required, it can all be so.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the declaration of both functions. Basically I just change the name and write the procedures as I want them. I have used this https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/de4af7ce6cc8f2c85e4b33cedb51fd88#file-oop_f2003_part_2-md as a reference

Comment: It looks to me like you are missing the `NOPASS` attribute on the type-bound procedure definitions.  Beyond that, I can't immediately see a problem with your attempt with generics.  Perhaps you could make a complete example with the generics, just in case there's something subtle?

Comment: Actually I'm not using NOPASS, I just haven't written the "this" variables in the code of the question, but now I have fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, there was something subtle. While writing the specific case, as you asked, I managed to solve the problem. In the program that uses the modules, I defined one of the variables that I use as input argument for the generic procedure with the wrong type. Because of this, the compiler was not able to match my call of the procedure with any of the generic ones defined. Now this is solved and working as expected. Thanks for your help